# Create a 4, 8 or 16 MHz signal

Tags: oscillator, oscilloscope

I have 4 MHz, 8 MHz and 16 MHz oscillator crystals. I just got a oscilloscope and will like to see this high frequency signals on the scope. This is the circuit I built:

[image]

[image]

I got that from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2FoDw_h5RU .

Why is it that when I connect the emitter of the 2n2222 transistor to the oscilloscope I get this:

[image]

**I only get that sine wave by connecting one side of scope probe. If I connect the other end of the probe to ground I get a flat line.** Moreover, the sine wave does not have a stable frequency. I get values ranging from 1 MHz to 1.5 MHz. If I remove the crystal I get the same frequency. It is as if the crystal is doing nothing.

### Edit

I have modified my circuit thanks for pointing it out on the comments. This is my new circuit:

[image]

The white cable is connected to the center leg (base) of transistor. I am still not able to see the 4MHz signal on the scope :/ .

Comment: At least the schematics do not match the built circuit. Look how the transistor is connected to the other circuitry. It is likely that the crystal is indeed doing nothing.

Comment: mHz (millihertz) or MHz (megahertz)?

Comment: great question I want MHz. I though they where the same sorry.

Comment: This is a somewhat high frequency so it's important to be aware of capacitive loading; a breadboard might have too much capacitance, and so could your probe. Can you set the probe to 10x mode, if it's currently set to 1x and has the switch to do so?

Comment: It is already on the 10x mode @nanofarad. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The transistor may be wired backwards - check the polarity.

Comment: EBC looks correct

Answer (score 2):

There is no connection to circuit ground from your scope probe and the supply is probably floating.